# Multiple Query on Jersey to select from multiple graphs

Tags: java, jersey, sparql

I want to have be able to run a URL that looks like

> host/to/source/search?query=something&terms=term1,term2,etc

What I am interested in the most is the **terms** parameter. I want to run a SPARQL query that will use the values of **terms** as names of graphs to search into.

```
    public String search(@QueryParam("query") String search_string, @QueryParam("match") @DefaultValue("") String match_string, @QueryParam("terms") @DefaultValue("") String terms_string)
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    List<String> splitted =Arrays.asList(terms_string.split(","));      

    VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph (hostURL, userName, password);
    //String replaceString = "//s"+"AND"+"//s";
    String srch = search_string.replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(" "), " AND ") ;
    VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create ("select ?s1 as ?uri, ?o1 as ?label where { { { select ?s1, ( ?sc * 3e-1 ) as ?sc, ?o1, ( sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?s1 ) ) ) as ?rank, ?g where { quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap { graph ?g { ?s1 ?s1textp ?o1 . ?o1 bif:contains '(" + srch + ")' option ( score ?sc ) . }}} order by desc ( ?sc * 3e-1 + sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?s1 ) ) ) limit 20 offset 0  } }}", set);;


     if (match_string.equals("exact")){
     vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(
                "select ?uri, ?label where {quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap { graph ?g { ?uri ?p ?label. FILTER (?label = '"+search_string+"'@en) .}}}",set
                );
    }
    ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(out, results);

    return out.toString();

}
```

At the moment I am taking the input of the user as a string and  then I split it, but it would be nicer to know how I can use it directly as a List using some Jersey propriety.

But the main issue is how to treat the List items as graphs for SPARQL to use in the queries above.

Comment: Have you considered `term=term1&term=term2` instead? Then (IIRC) you can use `@QueryParam("term") List<String> terms`.

Comment: That is also fine, but how can I then query to search in Graphs whose names are specified in **terms** considering that the number of these values can differ?

Comment: Try adding 'FROM <..term...>' for each term to the start of your query. That might do the trick.